# Is SVG Tag rendered if its not displayed

Tags: html, svg, rendering

Can someone tell me if an svg element embeded in HTML is rendered if display is set to none in class, id or style attribute? I am asking because i want to know if transformations are rendered faster if display is none!

```
<svg> 
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" fill="red" style="display:none"/>
</svg>
```

Will this be rerenderd (caluclated) if i do a transform like translate or scale on the whole svg element?

Comment: display:none stops things rendering. Not sure what else you're looking for here.

Comment: The question is if the svg engine calculates the transformations of an element if this element has display:none attribute and then dont' render the element itself or if the transfomations are not calculated for the element with dipslay:none attribute.

Comment: Depends on which rendering engine you're asking about and which version of that rendering engine, presumably.

Comment: The most interessting things here would be the engines used by newest versions of browsers like safari, firefox and chrome

Comment: If you want to do some performance tests on multiple browsers, go for it. The question is too broad here.

Comment: Why not inspect the DOM?

Comment: Because in the DOM i cannot see what is rendered and what is not rendered i just can see the tags and their css attributes